# Fetching Database Records With PDO's Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was using this code to fetch records from a database before:

```
function shapp_get_sections_with_company_id($db, $id)
{
    try
    {
        $que = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM company_sections WHERE company_id = '$id'");
        $result = $que -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex -> getMessage();
    }
}
```

It was working fine. It did its job.

But I'm trying to adapt it to use prepared statements instead.

I have modified the code to this, but I'm not having any luck. Apparently this returns an empty result set:

```
function shapp_get_sections_with_company_id($db, $id)
{
    try
    {
        $que = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM company_sections WHERE company_id = '?'");
        $que -> execute(array($id));
        $result = $que -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex -> getMessage();
    }
}
```

I have also tried returning "$que -> execute(...)" but it wasn't returning a result set.
Can I get any help to make this work with prepared statements, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the '?' in the prepare call

`$que = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM company_sections WHERE company_id = ?");`

Comment: *Facepalms* darn I can be a bit silly sometimes. Thank you, kind sir. That did the trick haha. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.